# SQL Query for getting all elements matching another element where there are at least X elements

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want a query that will give me all the items with an ID matching another item, where the group of matching items is larger than X.

Say I have two tables, submissions and submission_items.  Each submission has a submission_id and each submission_item has a foreign key that is the parent submission's submission_id.  Submissions can have multiple submission_items.

I want to get all the submissions that have more than X submission_items in them.

I tried this:

```
select submissions.*, submission_item.*
from submission
join submission_item ON submissions.submission_id = submission_item.submission_id
group by submission.submission_id
having count(*) > 1
```

It errored out saying it wanted other fields in the GROUP BY function.  How can I do this better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify a GROUP BY, fields in the SELECT statement must be either part of the group clause or part of an aggregate.

You need to find the IDs that you are interested in and then rejoin it back to the table.

```
SELECT * FROM 
submission si INNER JOIN
   (select submission_id
      from submission
      join submission_item ON submissions.submission_id = submission_item.submission_id
       group by submission.submission_id
       having count(*) > 1) c  
ON si.submission_id = c.submission_id
```

or you can group all the fields individually

```
select submissions.submission_id, submissions.x, submissions.y
from submission
join submission_item ON submissions.submission_id = submission_item.submission_id
group by submission.submission_id, submissions.x, submissions.y
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Wonderful, that worked perfectly.  I guess I was closer than I thought.